# how to group by and return sum row in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am stuck here. I have row in Postgres like this:

```
id      amount
a       5000
a       1500
a       500
b       2000
b       1000
c       4000
```

How is the sql syntax to get result like this?

```
id      amount
a       7000
b       3000
c       4000
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```