# Sum columns per row postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sum, rowsum

I have table like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE public."Payments"
(
  user_id integer,
  "1 month later" numeric(19,4),
  "2 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "3 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "4 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "5 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "6 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "7 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "8 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "9 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "10 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "11 months later" numeric(19,4),
  "12 months later" numeric(19,4)
```

with data inside for exampe like this:

```
INSERT INTO "Payments" ("user_id", "1 month later", "2 months later", "3 months later", "4 months later", "5 months later", "6 months later", "7 months later", "8 months later", "9 months later", "10 months later", "11 months later", "12 months later") VALUES (134329, 190, 190, 190, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I need to get summ for every user ID, there is a lot of them. Is any function in postgres which can do it swiftly?

Comment: First, why are you breaking 'x months later' into different columns. This violates the rules of normal form. What your trying to do is a simple sum. You should google this instead of posting a question here.

Comment: I agree with Eric.  You should stop and read a good book on relational data.  You're going down the wrong path.

Comment: it just a example, I have already this table in access, I need to convert it to psql and wright psql query

Answer (score 3):

This question is similar to this stackoverflow question. It is a simple use of the SUM aggregate function.

[how to group by and return sum row in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004655/how-to-group-by-and-return-sum-row-in-postgres)

```
SELECT user_id, SUM("1 month later") as "1 month later",SUM("2 months later") as "2 months later",SUM("3 months later") as "3 months later",SUM("4 months later") as "4 months later",SUM("5 months later") as "5 months later",SUM("6 months later") as "6 months later",SUM("7 months later") as "7 months later",SUM("8 months later") as "8 months later",SUM("9 months later") as "9 months later",SUM("10 months later") as "10 months later",SUM("11 months later") as "11 months later", SUM("12 months later") as "12 months later"
FROM public.payments
GROUP BY user_id
```

Additionally if the user wants one sum of all 12 columns then simply add the columns.

```
SELECT user_id, "1 month later" + "2 months later" + "3 months later" + "4 months later" + "5 months later" + "6 months later" + "7 months later" + "8 months later" + "9 months later" + "10 months later" + "11 months later" + "12 months later") as allMonthsLater    FROM public.payments
```

Comment: In this case you should make a comment, not an answer with a link to an existing answer. Besides, the link is not the same question, so it is no good.

Comment: In the case that I provided a code example, I made this an answer. I wanted to contribute but do not have enough points to make a comment (50 needed), however I can make an answer. I maintain that the question is the same but agree that the two examples are different.