# How to do sum of different values without duplicate

Tags: postgresql

How to do a sum of different values but same ID without duplicate different values on a column?

My Input in SQL Command.

```
    SELECT
      students.id        AS student_id,
      students.name,
      COUNT(*)           AS enrolled,
      c2.price           AS course_price,
      (COUNT(*) * price) AS paid
    FROM students
      LEFT JOIN enrolls e on students.id = e.student_id
      LEFT JOIN courses c2 on e.course_id = c2.id
    WHERE student_id NOTNULL
    GROUP BY students.id, students.name, c2.price
    ORDER BY student_id ASC;
```

My result.

```
 student_id |        name         | enrolled | paid 
------------+---------------------+----------+------
       1001 | Gulbadan Bálint     |        1 |   90
       1002 | Hanna Adair         |        5 |  450
       1003 | Taddeo Bhattacharya |        1 |   90
       1004 | Persis Havlíček     |        1 |   75
       1004 | Persis Havlíček     |        5 |  450
       1005 | Tory Bateson        |        1 |   90
       1007 | Dávid Fèvre         |        1 |   90
       1008 | Masuyo Stoddard     |        1 |   90
       1009 | Iiris Levitt        |        1 |   75
       1009 | Iiris Levitt        |        2 |  180
       1013 | Artair Kovač        |        1 |   30
       1013 | Artair Kovač        |        1 |   90
       1015 | Matilda Guinness    |        2 |  180
       1017 | Margarita Ek        |        1 |   90
       1018 | Misti Zima          |        3 |  270
       1019 | Conall Ventura      |        1 |   90
       1020 | Vivian Monday       |        2 |  180
```

My expected result.

```
 student_id |        name         | enrolled | paid 
------------+---------------------+----------+------
       1001 | Gulbadan Bálint     |        1 |   90
       1002 | Hanna Adair         |        5 |  450
       1003 | Taddeo Bhattacharya |        1 |   90
       1004 | Persis Havlíček     |        6 |  525
       1005 | Tory Bateson        |        1 |   90
       1007 | Dávid Fèvre         |        1 |   90
       1008 | Masuyo Stoddard     |        1 |   90
       1009 | Iiris Levitt        |        3 |  255
       1013 | Artair Kovač        |        2 |  120
       1015 | Matilda Guinness    |        2 |  180
       1017 | Margarita Ek        |        1 |   90
       1018 | Misti Zima          |        3 |  270
       1019 | Conall Ventura      |        1 |   90
       1020 | Vivian Monday       |        2 |  180
```

I think that the cause come from a GROUP BY command but it will throw an error if I do not write a GROUP BY price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use SUM() function.
Please see link below, maybe it's same case with you: 
[how to group by and return sum row in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004655/how-to-group-by-and-return-sum-row-in-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

You have excluded `course_price` column both in your current and expected result. It seems you had wrongly included that in `group by`.

```
SELECT
  students.id        AS student_id,
  students.name,
  COUNT(*)           AS enrolled,
  --c2.price         AS course_price, --exclude this in o/p?
  (COUNT(*) * price) AS paid
FROM students
  LEFT JOIN enrolls e on students.id = e.student_id
  LEFT JOIN courses c2 on e.course_id = c2.id
WHERE student_id NOTNULL
GROUP BY students.id, students.name --,c2.price --and remove it from here 
ORDER BY student_id ASC;
```

Comment: ERROR: column "c2.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. (COUNT(*) * price) AS paid

Comment: @PrasitTongpradit : I think you didn't understand what I was saying. if you  include `c2.price` in your select you should include it in `group by`  and you can't include it in select (without aggregation)if you have  not specified it in group by. If you want to understand how `group by` works, read a tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Oh, Thank you guy