# Counting word frequency

Tags: sql, postgresql, cpu-word

I am trying to sum the frequency of the words cumulatively in PostgreSQL

Here's my table (example)
[image: 1]

I need sum accumulative `frequency` for same words, for example the expected results is:

> **resize (100 + 85) = 185**
>
> **trabajar (75 + 73) = 148**
>
> **partir (64) = 64**

How can I make the query?

Comment: How about `SELECT word, SUM(frecuency) FROM yourtable GROUP BY word` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to group by and return sum row in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004655/how-to-group-by-and-return-sum-row-in-postgres)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT
    word
    , SUM(frecuency)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY word
```